# How to allow method of one class saw another class without import?

Tags: ios, objective-c, encapsulation

I have 2 class - Cars and Passenger.
In Car class I have method(Cars.h):

```
-(Passenger *)carWithLowestPassengers;
```

but class Car doesn`t see class Passenger without

```
#import Passenger.h
```

How I can solve the problem without using import?

Comment: use + method instead of -

Comment: `@class Passenger;` in .h, and in .m `#import Passenger.h`?

Comment: @class Car have #import Passenger - in .m, but, doesn`t have in .h

Comment: its confusing, actually the above method have passenger class `-(Passenger *)` return type so need to import in both classes.

Answer (score 0):

Solving is add 
    @class Passenger
in Car.h before @interface